# Polymer 1.x Data Binding Remote Values

Tags: polymer-1.0

This is the custom tag that I have in the HTML, I want {{value}} to change depending on the latency when the element loads.

```
<my-latency value={{value}}></my-state>
```

Below is the custom element I'm trying to write which does calculate the latency between the user and the server. But I dont know how to get the value of latency (which console.log's out perfectly) back to the value of the custom tag.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"> 

<script>

Polymer({
is:     "my-latency",
ready:  function() {
            socket = io('http://198.191.94.231:9000');

            socket.emit('latency', Date.now(), function(startTime) {
                var latency = Date.now() - startTime;
                console.log(latency); // returns: 203
            });
},
```

This is where it all starts to go wrong...

```
properties: {

latency: number,

    response: {
        value: latency,
        type: number,
        reflectToAttribute: true,
        readOnly: true,
        notify: true
    }

},

responseHandler: function(response) {
  this.value = latency;
}

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `ready()` is missing the assignment to `this.value`

```
var latency = Date.now() - startTime;
this.value = latency;
```